# Auto Scroll to bottom of div after ajax request

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

None of the answers in here work before people start marking as duplicate!

The poll function is a php file, simply gets the content of a text file, I want the browser to scroll to the bottom of the div content once the request (fires every 3 seconds) has completed. Here is some code

```
  <div id="content_div_id">

 </div>

<script>
$(function() {
  startRefresh();    
    });
    function startRefresh() {
        setTimeout(startRefresh,3000);
        $.post('pollchat.php', function(data) {
            $('#content_div_id').html(data);
        });

    }
```

My problem is after the 3 second refresh it is at the top of the chat content again. . . .

The entire thing is nested inside a window like so:

```
<div class="portlet-body chat-widget" style="overflow-y: auto; width: auto; height: 300px;">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <p class="text-center text-muted small">January 1, 2014 at 12:23 PM</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div id="content_div_id">

                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Out of box.. I'd prefer using `setInterval` over `setTimeout` here..

Comment: ok back in the box.. Need it to scroll to the bottom of the div content (or to a specific tag, I can always add one, ever time the Ajax request fires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is: your div with id="content_div_id" is not scrollable.

I created a simulation snippet, using a different values:

- Add style="overflow-y: hidden; width: auto; height: auto;" to div with id="content_div_id"
- I used jQuery.get instead of jQuery.post (you need to use post in your code)
- I used a different url (you need to use your url)
- I moved the timer inside the ajax so that it starts again and again
  (You could use a settimer, but if you do so you need to plan how and when to stop it)
- I used jQuery append instead of jQuery html because I assume you want to append instead of substitute. It's up to you which one you need.

```js
var i = 0;
function startRefresh() {
  $.get('https://api.github.com/users', function(data) {
    $('#content_div_id').append(i + ': ' + data[0].id + '<br>');
    i += 1;
    var myDiv = $('div.portlet-body.chat-widget');
    myDiv.scrollTop(myDiv[0].scrollHeight - myDiv[0].clientHeight);
    setTimeout(startRefresh, 300);
  });
}
$(function () {
  startRefresh();
});
```

```css
#content_div_id {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="portlet-body chat-widget" style="overflow-y: auto; width: auto; height: 300px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <p class="text-center text-muted small">January 1, 2014 at 12:23 PM</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="content_div_id" style="overflow-y: hidden; width: auto; height: auto;">

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`window.scrollTo(0,document.getElementById('content_div_id').scrollHeight);`

Comment: Im a c# programmer by trade so I am a little green when it comes to js, where and how would I impliment that?

Comment: The Div itself is nested in here

Answer (score 0):

Apart from my suggestion of using `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`, here is the code you need to use to scroll to `bottom` of the `div`.

```
$(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    startRefresh();
  }, 3000)
});

function startRefresh() {
  $.post('pollchat.php', function(data) {
    $('#content_div_id').html(data);

    $('#content_div_id').scrollTop($('#content_div_id')[0].scrollHeight);//scrolls to bottom of div #content_div_id
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the snippet. it has what you want.

```js
$(function() {
  
  startRefresh();    
    });
    function startRefresh() {
        setTimeout(startRefresh,3000);

   // put this in your ajax $.Post callback Like below
   // $.post('pollchat.php', function(data) {
     //   $('#content_div_id').html(data);
     //     var wtf    = $('#content_div_id');
     //     var height = wtf[0].scrollHeight;
      //    wtf.scrollTop(height);
   // });
       var wtf    = $('#content_div_id');
  var height = wtf[0].scrollHeight;
  wtf.scrollTop(height);
    }
```

```css
#content_div_id{
width:100%;
  height:300px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="content_div_id">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
 </div>
```